# Null Pointer Exception on setAdapter Action for Expandable List View

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I try to run my application, but i encounter null pointer exception at setAdapter(listAdapter) action.

**Main Activity Java code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Assigning main activity name for drawing
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time);
    // Find the ListView resource and assign to ListView Object created
    ExpandableListView mainListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.textClock);
    // Initialize adapter with data by parsing JSON
    listAdapter = new TwocolumnAdapter(this, parseJSONString(readFile()), headersList);
    //Saving the reference to prepare new adapter when reload is needed
    object = this;
    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

**Main Activity XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" tools:context=".Time" android:background="@color/accent_material_dark" android:orientation="vertical">
<ExpandableListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textClock" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:format24Hour="@android:string/yes" />
```

I searched several SO posts, cross checked id(s) etc, tried all solutions but could not nail this issue.

Any suggestions or pointers are highly appreciated.

[## Please check complete code on GITHUB](https://github.com/Sudarshan-/Time_Zones_Across_World_V1)

Error Logs

```
12-18 00:36:59.609  19893-19893/sudharshanapps.clock E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sudharshanapps.clock, PID: 19893
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sudharshanapps.clock/sudharshanapps.clock.Time}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sudharshanapps.clock.Time.onCreate(Time.java:264)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: whats the name of "Main Activity XML" layout?

Comment: @Jorgesys: Thanks for your response, it is "activity_time.xml"

Comment: Thanks in fact im seeing your code at Github.

Comment: try setting break points in your TwocolumnAdapter at all the overridden methods. My first instinct is the NPE could be happening in the getChild or similar method that's called as part of setAdapter, assuming listAdapter isn't null. Can you also post the full error from logcat?

Comment: @DaveS: I have added logs, can you please provide some pointers

Comment: where is your closing tag for linear layout?

Comment: Obviously something is null at line 264 in Time.java. Which is probably mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter); Have you checked that both mainListView and listAdapter aren't null themselves?

Comment: @BrandonLing: It is a typo, there is closing tag in my code

Comment: @DaveS: Awesome, mainListView is null, but If you look at `Main Activity XML`, there is `ExpandableListView`Tag with id `android:id="@+id/textClock"`, I think it is unable to find view, any ideas here, Thanks for your pointers so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is activity_time.xml in the Layout-v17 folder. This is the layout that will be used for API 17 and higher. It looks like in this case it's actually loading this xml instead of the one you expect. Try deleting it or making it the same as the main version of activity_time.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainListView" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```